# Shopping cart using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I am trying to make a shopping cart.I can add books to the cart and empty whole cart.But I cant remove individual cart items.I could add one item to the cart and remove it using remove item hyperlink.But after adding multiple items,I cant remove items using hyperlink. What should I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<?php include './menu.php';?>
</div>


<div id="navigator">
</div>

<div id="section">

<?PHP
$name=$_SESSION['userName'];
$email=$_SESSION['myEmail'];
require("connection.php");


?><h2>
Welcome <?PHP echo($name); ?>,</h2>
<?PHP require("menu2.php"); ?><hr>

<?PHP 

require("connection.php");
$Query=("select * from tb_book");
$result=mysql_query($Query);
?>

<?php
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {

        case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_book WHERE bookID='" . $_GET["bookID"] . "'");
            $productByCode=mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $itemArray = array($productByCode["bookID"]=>array('bName'=>$productByCode["bName"], 'bookID'=>$productByCode["bookID"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode["price"]));


            //$itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["bookID"]=>array('bName'=>$productByCode[0]["bName"], 'bookID'=>$productByCode[0]["bookID"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode["bookID"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode["bookID"] == $k)
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
    break;
    case "remove":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($_GET["bookID"] == $k)
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                    //if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                    //  unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }
        }
    break;
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
    break;  
}
}
?>



<table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>


<td width="70%">
<div id="product-grid">
    <div class="txt-heading">Products</div>
    <?php
    $product = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_book ORDER BY bName ASC");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($product)) { 

    ?>
        <div class="product-item">
            <form method="post" action="buyBook.php?action=add&bookID=<?php echo $row["bookID"]; ?>">
            <div><img src="./books/<?PHP echo($row['image']); ?>" height="100" width="100" /></div>
            <div><?php echo $row["bName"]; ?></div>
            <div class="product-price"><?php echo "INR &nbsp;".$row["price"]; ?></div>
            <div><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btnAddAction" /></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php
            }

    ?>
</div>
</td>

<td width="30%" valign="top">


<div id="shopping-cart">
<div class="txt-heading">Shopping Cart <a id="btnEmpty" href="buyBook.php?action=empty">Empty Cart</a></div>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
    $item_total = 0;
?>  
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
<tr>

<th><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
<th><strong>Price</strong></th>
<th></th>
</tr>   
<?php       
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
        ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $item["bName"]; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?></td>
                <td align=right><?php echo "INR ".$item["price"]; ?></td>
                <td><a href="buyBook.php?action=remove&bookID=<?php echo $item["bookID"]; ?>" class="btnRemoveAction">Remove Item</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
        $item_total += ($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]);
        }
        ?>      
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align=right><strong>Total:</strong> <?php echo "INR ".$item_total; ?></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>        
  <?php
}
?>
</div>
</table>
<br /><br /><center>
    <form name="checkout" action="buyBook_action.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="PROCEED" />
    </form>
    </center>
</td>

</tr>
</table>




</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors? Try to echo the  the content of `$_SESSION["cart_item"]` after clicking the Remove Item link. Just put this  `var_dump($_SESSION["cart_item"]);` inside your "remove" case. And see if the ID is unset in that session variable.

Comment: tried var_dump. ID is not unset after removing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

```
if (!empty($_GET["bookID"])) {

  foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $subKey => $subArray){

    if($subArray["bookID"] == $_GET["bookID"]){ /* CHECK IF THERE IS A BOOKID THAT HAS THE SAME $_GET["bookID"] */
      unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$subKey]);
    }

  } /* END OF FOREACH */

}
```

You store your array with sub-array of `bName`, `bookID`, `quantity`, and `price` in your session variable. The code I have provided will check the `$_GET["bookID"]` if it is in a sub-array of `bookID`. And if it does found one, it will remove that set of array.

```
[
  {"bName":"Physics","bookID":"1","quantity":"1","price":"1100.00"},
  {"bName":"Algebra","bookID":"2","quantity":"2","price":"1200.00"},
  {"bName":"Calculus","bookID":"3","quantity":"3","price":"1300.00"}
]
```

#### Recommendation

Create an extra table. Lets name it `cart_table`

```
cart_id  |  userID  |  bookID  |
---------+----------+----------+
   1     |    1     |     1    |
   2     |    1     |     2    |
   3     |    1     |     3    |
```

`userID` column is the user's ID and `bookID` column is the book's ID that the user puts into the cart.

The advantage of this is even if the user logs-out, when this user returns, he/she will still be able to see the books that he/sher puts into his/her cart.

Comment: No...it's not getting removed

Comment: By the way, where is your `session_start()`? Try displaying again the content of your session array inside your "remove" case.

Comment: session_start() is written in menu.php page,which is included in the header section.

Comment: Have you checked if the "Remove Item" link has the right corresponding ID? Like if you hover your mouse pointer to that link, you should see that it will go to, for example, `buyBook.php?action=remove&bookID=1`. Or inspect the element of the "Remove Item" link if it has the right bookID.

Comment: echo($_GET["bookID"]) is showing the right id of book,which I'm trying to remove

Comment: Try my updated answer. I just take a closer look how you store array in your session variable.

Comment: Updated code solved the problem... Thanks a lot.. :)